# lack of "/" character in express.js HTTP .get() request returning TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, express, http

Trying to concatenate value to end of URL for request to server.

urltemp2 works correct and sends the request BUT like 192.168.666.666:5000/result=/value1&value2

I don't want the "/" after "/result=/"

urltemp1 returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

//myvar is 6-digit number
//serverURL is my server's IP address, e.g. 192.168.666.666:5000/

```
var urltemp1 = window.location.pathname.replace("/result=", "") + "&" + myvar;
var urltemp2 = window.location.pathname.replace("result=", "") + "&" + myvar;
getRequest(urltemp2);

async function getRequest(desc) {
       const searchUrl = "result=";
       var res = await fetch(serverURL + searchUrl + desc, {
           method: "GET",
           headers: {
               "Content-Type": "application/json",
           },
       })
           .then(response => {
               if (!response.ok) {
                   throw new Error("HTTP status " + response.status);
               }
               return response.json();
           })
           .then(res => {
               nextFunc(res);
               window.history.pushState(null, null, "result=" + desc);
           })
           .catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
           });
   }
```

The result I would like is 192.168.666.666:5000/result=value1&value2 without an error saying my value is not worth nothing, thank you.

Comment: There must be a `?` before the search part of the URL, for example, `192.168.666.666:5000/?result=value1&value2`.

Comment: For the search with 1 value, a get request with URL 192.168.666.666:5000/result=value1 works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Okay, turns out I was not handling the request to the server properly, leading to an empty array [] being sent back as a response, which could not be resolved by my frontend and was caught by the error handler

```
.catch(error => {
               console.log(error);
           });
```

Fixing my server request handling fixed the issue